# Java8 Supplier that is an optional Consumer

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

I can explain this one only with the example.

We have the main class, `AppServer`. It holds also several application-wide components.

```
AppServer app = new AppServer(config, ...);
```

Now we need to provide a supplier that will act as a factory for some `Foo` instances. This supplier will be called several times in the loop to create some amount of the `Foo` instances. By using the supplier, we allow users to provide their own implementation of the `Foo`. Note that `Foo` is NOT our class and we can NOT change it.

The only problem is that `Foo` requires some of the components from the application. They need to be injected/provided to the `FooImpl`.

This can be written like this:

```
app.setFooSupplier(() -> new FooImpl(app.component()));
```

This is kind of ugly for me and wonder if there is a better way to do this? Here are some ideas so far...

**(1)** Inject dependencies after supplier is used (IoC way).

Dependencies are defined with the setters. So we have something like (inside of `AppServer`), in sudo:

```
Foo foo = fooSupplier.get();
maybeInject(foo, component1);
maybeInject(foo, component2);
...
```

What component is injected depends if the setter is there. Alternatively, we can have `Component1Aware` interfaces and do the same like:

```
Foo foo = fooSupplier.get();
if (foo instanceof Component1Aware) {
    ((Component1Aware)foo).setComponent1(component1);
}
...
```

which is basically the same.

I would like to have dependencies in constructor, so to express they need to be set.

**(2)** Use optional Consumer

Create a `Supplier` instance for `FooImpl` that is in the same time `Consumer` of the `AppServer`. Something like:

```
public class FooImplSupplier implements Supplier<Foo>, Consumer<AppServer> {
    ...
}
```

and then we can register this supplier very easily:

```
app.setFooSupplier(new FooImplSupplier());
```

and after the supplier creates an instance (in `AppServer`) we do the following:

```
Foo foo = fooSupplier.get();
if (foo instanceof Consumer) {
    ((Consumer)foo).accept(this);
}
```

Wdyt?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to implement your own dependency injection framework. Why not use one of the established dependency injection frameworks such as Spring or Google Guice?

Comment: @Jesper I wouldn't use a framework to replace a one liner.  IMHO That is a extreme overkill.

Comment: Even if I use the smallest ioc like [Petite](http://jodd.org/doc/petite/), it would be a extreme overkill. Just need to wire few components, thats all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always favour passing mandatory settings via the constructor (or a static factory method)  The IoC style I prefer is

```
app.setFooSupplier(() -> new FooImpl(app.component()));
```

or you could write the following if `app.component()` returns the same thing each time.

```
Component comp = app.component();
app.setFooSupplier(() -> new FooImpl(comp));
```

This is by far the simplest and the hardest to get wrong. e.g. you can't pass an argument 0 or multiple times, or try to use the Supplier before it is initialised.

Comment: Does it bother you to use `app` on both sides of this equation? We are telling `app` to use some instance (supplied by `Supplier`), with data that is already in the `app` - and that seems like un necessary step... wdyt?

Comment: @игор Not really, but if it bothers you, you could use a local variable, if the value doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

It is not unusual to provide context information to a supplier. The problem you have is that you are fixed on the `Supplier` interface which distracts you from the simple solution. Instead of trying to combine the `Supplier` with a `Consumer` you should use a `Function`:

```
void setFooProvider(Function<AppServer,Foo> f) {
  this.fooProvider=Objects.requireNonNull(f);
}
// …
// in a method within the same class:
    Foo foo=fooProvider.apply(this);
```

Caller:

```
app.setFooProvider(appArg -> new FooImpl(appArg.component()));
```

I changed the method’s name from `…Supplier` to `…Provider` to make clear that the role of the provided argument is not tight to a particular `interface`. You may use `Supplier`, `Function`, `BiFunction`, or a custom `interface`, whatever fits.

Now the specified provider uses it’s argument and doesn’t capture values from its surrounding context which makes it invariant (and with the current implementation it will be a singleton).

Note that it is still possible to implement provider functions which simply ignore the argument so the original functionality of the `Supplier` based solution is not lost.